# How to hide or modify <pk> in url in Django app?

Tags: python, django

In my url.py I have:

```
path('gpd/<pk>/',       views.gpd,          name='gpd'),
```

my view.py looks like:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def gpd(request,pk):

    current_gpd = get_gpd(pk)

    context = {'current_gpd ':current_gpd , 
               'pk':pk, }

    return render(request, 'app/gpd/gpd_form.html', context)

def get_gpd(id):
    return GPD.objects.get(id=id)
```

I have noticed, that when my logined user change manually `pk` - then he has an access to page with another pk. How to prevent it?

my GPG model:

```
class GPD(models.Model):
    id                      = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    employee                = models.ForeignKey(Employee,   verbose_name='Employee',    on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='+')

class Employee(models.Model):
    id                  = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name                = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Name')
```

Comment: What is `pk` here? The primary key of a ...?

Comment: In my case: pk - is an instance id of model GPD

Comment: yes, but how is it related to the user. Usually filtering is done based on the "owner", or something similar of the object. So the view checks if the user has the right to see that object.

Comment: We need some more details. Let's start with the `GPD` model. Also explain how we should decide whether or not a user can access a particulare `GPD` instance or not?

Comment: I have to group of users: manager - has access to his own gpd + employees gpd; and employee - has access only to his own gpd.

Comment: I have an idea how to override all my functions in `view.py`, but I am looking for something like hash <pk> in `url.py` 'case i have a lot of function with <pk> from different models.

Comment: So basically, you want to prevent the user from accessing pages directly from the url just by incrementing or decrementing the pk ?

Comment: @badprogrammer yes, it is exactly what i want

Comment: In that case, the UUIDField can be used.
...
import uuid
...
class classname(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True;
        default=uuid.uuid4,editable=False)
...

You might also have to change the path in urls.py to something like :
path('<uuid:pk>',viewname,urlname)

Answer (score -1):

```
def get_gpd(id,user):
    return GPD.objects.get(id=id, employee=user)

so pass in the request.user
```

Comment: Please see [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for details on how to provide quality answers. It's useful to provide context and details on why this might be an ideal solution.